# SQL query after clicking a link

Tags: php, javascript

I have a link that i want to execute a query to the database after it's clicked and then reload the page. From what i read, it could be done using javascript, but i can't figure it out.

EDIT

Forgot to mention that i want to send 4 variables to the script and i can't use GET because i have htaccess set to modify my URL.

Comment: You can use AJAX for it.

Comment: Please put some code. like your html

Comment: Do you want to submit some values? What kind of query you want to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to use these concepts:

1. A JavaScript function to submit the from values
2. PHP code

You need to user these code:

```
 <a href = "javascript:submit()">Submit</a>
 <form action = "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" method = "post">
 <input type = "hidden" value = "some value"/>
 <input type = "hidden" value = "some value"/>
 <input type = "hidden" value = "some value"/>
 <input type = "hidden" value = "some value"/>
 </form>
<?php
//Connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect('host','user','password','db_name');
if($conn){
     $query = "SOME QUERY";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
?>
```

In your `JavaScript` function write a code to submit the from clicking the submit link.

Comment: I already have the values when the button is clicked, there's no need for a form and i can't put the php script on the same page because there are more scripts than one. I don't know if this makes any sense to you, but i want the button to send some values to an outside script and then reload the same page (and when this happens, the button will have a different action, that's why i can't use this method)

Comment: You can use the header function in php. Without using SELF_PHP you can use something as submit.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jquery code which will solve your issue. Write this code in a javascript function. onclick event of that button should call this function. Write all your db coding in yourpage.php.

```
url = "yourpage.php";

    $.get
    (
        url,
        {
            'act'       :'getdata'
        },
        function(responseText)
        {           
            strData = responseText;

            $('#div_id').html(strData);

        },
        "html"
    );
```

It will work.

Check this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: How can i send some values to yourpage.php using this method? Will $.get work if my URL is modified by htaccess ?